# setInterval nofunciona como es esperado

Tags: javascript, typescript, setinterval

Necesito que la función se ejecute 250 veces por segundo, para ello trato de hacer uso de setInterval pero esto no parece funcionar como esperaría.

Pensé todo funcionaría a la perfección pero al hacer el testing me daba error.
Luego de intentar multiples cosas probé usando un timeOut y el interval y para mi sorpresa el interval se tarda mucho más en terminar que el timeOut.

El timeOut es 1000/250 para lograr que se llame esas 250 veces cada segundo

#### Estoy utilizando el siguiente código

```js
const duration = 2000; // 2 seconds in milliseconds


/**
* @description call the function 250 times per second
* @params {number} duration duration in milliseconds
*/
const timer = (duration) => {

    const time = 1000; //A second in milliseconds
    const timesPerSeconds = 250;
    const timeOut = time/timesPerSeconds; // Waiting time on each call
    let counter = 1;

    /**
    * the number of calls required according to the duration
    */
    const necessaryCalls= duration/timeOut;
    
    /**
    * add eight seconds because it is the time that the interval 
    * will take before the first call
    */
    setTimeout(()=> console.log(`${duration} milliseconds completed`), duration+timeOut)
    const intervalId =setInterval(()=> {

        if(counter >= necessaryCalls){
            clearInterval(intervalId)
            console.log(`Completed, called ${counter} times`)
        }
        counter++;
    }, timeOut)
}

timer(duration)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo más cercano a lo que quieres hacer es [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), que intenta ejecutarse una vez por cada refresco de pantalla: si tu monitor funciona a 60Hz, se ejecutará 60 veces, si es de 144Hz, se ejecutará 144 veces.
Por supuesto, esto depende de lo pesado que sea el código que le pases a esta función, si no le da tiempo a ejecutarse entre 2 refrescos pues se ejecutará menos veces, bajando los FPS:

El problema que tiene es que, como depende de la máquina en la que se ejecuta, tienes que calcular el tiempo pasado entre dos ejecuciones para que tus animaciones vayan siempre a la misma velocidad.

```js
const duration = 2000; // 2 seconds in milliseconds
const timeBetweenExecutions=[];

const timer = (duration) => {
    let counter = 1;
    let keepGoing = true;
    let previous = performance.now();
    
    // When to stop
    setTimeout(()=> {
      console.log(`${duration} milliseconds completed`);
      keepGoing = false;
    }, duration);
    
    const repetitiveFunction = () => {
        const now = performance.now();
        timeBetweenExecutions.push(now-previous);
        previous = now;
        counter++;
        if(!keepGoing){
            console.log(`Completed, called ${counter} times`);
            timeBetweenExecutions.shift(); //la primera vez no pasó tiempo!
            console.log('Average time between executions:', 
                    timeBetweenExecutions.reduce((a,b) => a + b) / timeBetweenExecutions.length);
                    console.log('Some times:', timeBetweenExecutions.slice(50,80).toString());
            return;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(repetitiveFunction);
    }
    repetitiveFunction();
}

timer(duration)
```

No es tan rápido como quieres (a menos que tengas un monitor que tenga un refresco de 250Hz) pero sí es muy estable.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas agotando la pila de llamadas del Interval, Javascript funciona con un **hilo unico** y por lo tanto el cumplimiento estricto de los Intervals no esta garantizado, tenes un articulo que documenta este comportamiento [John Resign How JavaScript Timers Work](https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/). Es un tema extenso sobre los callbacks y como funciona el codigo asincrono.

Ademas de que el `setInterval` y el `timeOut` funcionan de distinta manera, ademas tienen prioridad diferente en la pila de llamadas.

Si pones un `timeOut()` de 2 segundos seguramente se ejecutara muy cerca de esa cantidad de tiempo, pero si pones 1 milisegundo la precisión bajara, y si además en vez de un `timeOut` pones un `setInterval` cada 1 milisegundo estarás enviando un callback a la pila de llamadas cada 1 milisegundo que además deberá ejecutar código dentro. En resumen: mientras mas grande sea el intervalo de tiempo mas preciso será, y dependerá también de las capacidades de tu procesador.

> *Dado que JavaScript solo puede ejecutar una pieza de código a la vez (debido a su naturaleza de subproceso único), cada uno de estos
> bloques de código "bloquea" el progreso de otros eventos asincrónicos.
> Esto significa que cuando ocurre un evento asincrónico (como un clic
> del mouse, un temporizador activado o una solicitud XMLHttpRequest
> completada) se pone en cola para ejecutarse más tarde (la forma en que
> ocurre esta cola seguramente varía de un navegador a otro, así que
> considere esto para ser una simplificación). - How Javascript Timers Works*

Tanto los intervals como los timeouts son codigo asincrono.

Comment: Alguna idea para solucionar el problema o simplemente no es posible?

Comment: @Jhon Yo no entiendo, cual es el problema? Podrías explicar el contexto del asunto, porqué, desde fuera querer ejecutar una función JS 250 veces por segundo parece algo sin sentido

Comment: No es posible, es algo inherente al Javascript ejecutado en navegadores. Es distinto a los lenguajes que usan programación multihilo como Java. Si la tenes más clara una vez sepas JavaScript a un nivel medio podes ver este video que explica a la perfección cómo funciona el Event Loop https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dX2lThXc0p4

Comment: @Yussef Necesito saber por que porcentaje de la ejecución va una animación. Por ejemplo si una animación tarda 2s y desde el inicio de su ejecución ha pasado 1s quiero poder saber que va por el 50% y a su vez poder detenerla, pausarla, volverla hacía atrás en el tiempo y reiniciarla. Para ello necesité desarrollar una librería que haga animaciones o transiciones la cual ya hice y funciona con porcentajes por lo que quiero hacer 250 o 125 cambios por segundo en la pantalla. Si tienes alguna sugerencia para resolver mi problema de otra forma, sin dicha librería o esta función por favor dímelo.

Comment: @Jhon Tú dices `quiero hacer 250 o 125 cambios por segundo en la pantalla`, pero pasa que los monitores tienen una tasa de refresco de 60Hz (y de alta gama tienen 100, 120 y 144), o sea que tienes una limitante de hardware insalvable. Yo además tengo la impresión de que el render del navegador no puede andar por sobre 60FPS, pero es una suposición a partir de que requestAnimationFrame tiene ese límite. El ojo humano ya detecta una animación fluida desde de los 25FPS, y las pruebas que hice a tu código el problema desaparece con 100FPS. Entonces mi sugerencia es que te ajustes a 60FPS como max

Comment: exactamente como te dicen, para que queres 250fps? 60 va de sobra

Comment: @Yussef requestAnimationFrame no está limitado a 60, en mi respuesta hay código que en mi máquina se ejecuta 75 veces por segundo porque es la tasa de refresco de mi pantalla

Comment: @PabloLozano Justo estaba leyendo eso en la documentación `El número de devoluciones de llamada suele ser de 60 veces por segundo, pero generalmente coinciden con la frecuencia de actualización de pantalla`, así que tienes toda la razón